# Restore the style of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building my own home page. I find someone's page good, and downloaded its page source, and open it locally in my browser, what is strange is that the contents are there, but the style (frame, position...) is lost. I would like to know what is missing to restore the style...

I guess it is related to the `head` part of the source, probably the `css`or `js` file... I copy them here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylev5.css" />
    <title>homepage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      $(window).ready(function () {
        var codes = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
        // codes = [65];
        $(window).keydown(function (event) {
          var code = event.keyCode;
          if (code == codes.shift()) {
            if (codes.length == 0) {
              $(".konami").fadeIn("slow");
              var h = $(".konami").height() - $(".links").height();
              $(".links").css("margin-top", h/2);
            }
          } else {
            codes = [];
          }
        });
        $(".door").click(function () {
          $(".konami").fadeOut("slow");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
....
```

I don't know `javascript`, could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the files mentioned in the `<link>` and `<script>` tags to the directory your `.html` file is in.

Point your browser to `http://website-you-are-stealing-from.com/stylev5.css` and download the file. Same goes for the Javascript.

P.S.: Don't steal people's website designs ;)

Comment: Stealing is a form of appreciation. Learn from how others do, add your personal touch and name sources if you are just copying.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Chrome, you can navigate to the page and hit *Ctrl-S* to save the entire page including links, scripts, styles and all.  This often works pretty well, and is almost perfect for static pages.  Remember though, if you're dealing with dynamic pages, there will be server-side logic that you won't be able to download or replicate.